# What's the best practice to save multiple foreign keys in "create"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a crud with nested resource.

`Post` `has_many :comments` and my `comments` `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :post`. When I am adding a new comment, I am currently doing something like this in the create action of the comment controller:

```
@post = Post.where(id: params[:post_id]).first
@post_comments = @post.post_comments.build
@post_comments.update_attributes(params[:post_comment])
@post_comments.user = current_user

if @post_comments.save
  ...
```

I also saw this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978113 which seems to do what I am doing.

This seems choppy, and I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly. Is there a better way? What is the best practice?

Comment: As a side note, you should use `Post.find(params[:post_id])`

Comment: I think that's actually worse. Rails 4 completely deprecates the finders, so I adopted the `where`.

Comment: Only old-style finder `find(:all, :conditions = {})` and dynamic finder methods `find_by_post_id` are deprecated: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations Finding by id with `find` is still good and recommended: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any defined best practice for this but with your code, you don't need the call to `update_attributes`.  There are 2 ways to save both foreign keys (actually 4 ways, if you're goining to build the comment from the user)

**First option:**

```
params[:post_comment].merge!(user_id: current_user.id)
@post = Post.where(id: params[:post_id]).first
@post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(params[:post_comment])

if @post_comment.save
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

**Second option:**

```
@post = Post.where(id: params[:post_id]).first
@post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(params[:post_comment])
@post_comment.user = current_user

if @post_comment.save
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Just a note though, you should use the singular form if you're dealing with a singular resource so `@post_comments` should be `@post_comment`

Comment: I think I understood the singular resource part, but just making sure. You're not talking about my routes right? I currently have `resources comments` in there.