# Multiple Foreign Keys for Rails record - Unknown Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app that allows users to comment on a single "work" (think blog post). The associations in the models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works  
  has_many :comments

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :work
```

In the comments table, a record has the following fields:

id
content
user_id
created_at
updated_at
work_id

In my Comments controller, I have the following Create action:

```
def create
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @work.comments.create(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      #flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'activities'
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to associate both the user AND the work to the comment but I get the following error message when I try to create a comment:

```
Unknown action

The action 'update' could not be found for CommentsController
```

I'm trying to use the following StackOverflow answer as a guide but the solution is not working for me: 
[Multiple Foreign Keys for a Single Record in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977267/multiple-foreign-keys-for-a-single-record-in-rails-3)

**EDIT:**
I have a add comment form on the works#show action:

```
def show 
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  @comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Work", trackable_id: @work).all
  @comments = @work.comments.order("created_at DESC").where(work_id: @work ).all 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
```

The Comment form itself:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post a comment!" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I also have an update method on the Comments controller:

```
def update
     @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      flash[:success] = "Comment updated"
      redirect_to @comment
    end
  end
```

Comment: Note that you're saving the record twice. `@comment = @work.comments.create(params[:comment])` attempts to persist the record, and you're saving it *again* with `@comment.save`. You should be using `@comment = @work.comments.new(params[:comment])`

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
The action 'update' could not be found for CommentsController
```

So, the issue is that your form is trying to call an `update` action on the `CommentsController`.  This is unrelated to adding both the `User` and the `Work` instance as foreign keys.  Your code for that seems right.

Comment: Hmm..I just edited my post to include more info. Could it be that I have the add comment form on the work#show page? My code there must not be right.

Comment: The issue is with your `form_for(@comment)`.  So this neat little helper will submit your form to the `create` action if the comment has not been saved, but to the `update` action if the comment has already been saved.  My hunch is that if you look in the db, you will see a comment row in there and the form is trying to update that record, but cannot find the update action.

Comment: You're right. The db is filled with blank records. The form creates the row but doesn't do anything afterward. What should I change on the comment form?

Comment: You need to add a `update` method to your controller to allow for managing these saved comments.

Comment: I already have an update action on my Comments controller. I'll post the code when I get a chance ( not home at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

For sure if you persist the comment to the database during the `show` action:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])
```

Then the form helper will build an update form rather than a create form (because the model already exists):

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
```

If the desired action is to POST a comment create from the show page then try `build`ing the comment in the show action:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the code to build but now the error message states that it can't find the create action for the CommentsController